# Profile fields shown during registration

Tags: users

I want to have one profile with some fields shown during registration and other fields not shown during registration. I can't seem to do this.

I am using the Profile2 module (drupal.org/project/profile2)

From what I can see, a profile selected to "Show during user account registration" will show all fields associated with that profile during registration. And a profile that is not selected to show during registration will not show any fields during registration.

I am not seeing any options within a profile to make a given field override the selected setting for the profile.

So currently I have two profiles for the users - one with the fields I want shown during registration and a second profile with the fields I don't want shown during registration.

The result is two profile links for the user, which is not what I want.

How can I make a given profile field override the profile's registration setting?

---

Thanks for your answer, CR47. I am currently unable to select your response as the answer or even add comments because of a JavaScript problem. I will select your answer as soon as the error is resolved.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188125/dreaded-error-stack-overflow-requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [field permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module should help with this.  You can set individual permissions on fields of user and node entities.  If you set a field permission to be visible to only authenticated users, then it won't show on the sign up page.

Here is an example with screenshots:

These are the fields I have in Profile 2
[image]

When editing the field for "Will not be visible" I scroll to Field visiblity and permissions and select custom.  Then check the types of users that can see/edit values for themselves and others.  By default everything is only checked for admin.
[image]

Then when going to create an account you can see the "Will not be visible" field is not visible.
[image]